# Unresolved reference: moveFocus

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm using jetpack compose with kotlin to my current project, but I'm having this wired problem. For my OutLinedTextField I'm using `ImeAction.Search` but for the action, I cannot hide my keyboard.

```
keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onSearch = {
                                FocusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                                viewModel.SearchProduct(searchItem.value)
                            })
```

I cannot access `moveFocus` the error says `Unresolved reference: moveFocus` I have no idea.

Comment: I never thought about it, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Method [`moveFocus(FocusDirection)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/focus/FocusManager#moveFocus(androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusDirection)) cannot be accessed like that.

Obain an instance: `val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current` and 
then use that instance: `focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)`.

This works within the scope of a `@Composable` 
and the target needs `Modifier.focusable()`.